# Receiving information from a html checkbox with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

So the scrip receives a array of file names from a node.js function and creates a checklist. which works fine. but it should make a new array with the selected file names and parse it back to a new function. 
But the array that gets filled is by input from the function.and not the actual file names.

languages and packages used: Html, css, Javascript, node.js and electronjs

How the script looks:

```
<script>
        const scan = require('../src/scan.js');
        const merge = require('../src/merge.js');
        scan.filesscan('tests', files => {
                files.forEach(file => {
                        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML +=
                                '<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes">' + file + '<br>';
                });
        });

        function next(){            
            var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=mycheckboxes]:checked');
            alert(checkedBoxes);
            merge.fileMerge(checkedBoxes);
            location.href = 'test.html';
        }


</script>
```

Input from the scan.js {'a.txt','b.txt','c.txt'}

Expected array from the selected items {'a.txt','c.txt'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, JavaScript is giving you what you are asking for:

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[...');
```

`querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList` of `HTMLInputElement` (in this case).

If you want the actual file names, the easiest way would be for you to set every `checkbox`'s `value` property with the filename:

```
files.forEach(file => {
                    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML +=
                            '<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckboxes" value="' + file + '">' + 
file + '<br>';
            });
```

Then you can get the filenames (in `next` function):

```
var checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=mycheckboxes]:checked');
var files = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkedBoxes.length; i++) {
    files.push(checkedBoxes[i].value);
}
```

And no, you can't use `forEach` with a variable of type `NodeList` as it is not an array, but an array-like object.

Comment: Thanks mate when I got home I realised I left out the value, didnt know it outputted as a nodelist other then a arraylist thanks.